# What is wrong with this google test code?

Tags: googletest

The following test code:

```
TEST(StringTests, doubleToString)
{
TSTRING exp_str[]={"2.560000","0.000000","-2222.222000"};
double inp_str[]={2.56,0,-2222.222};
TSTRING return_str[2];

 CMIString::doubleToString(inp_str[0],return_str[0]);
 EXPECT_EQ(exp_str[0],return_str[0]);

  CMIString::doubleToString(inp_str[1],return_str[1]);
 EXPECT_EQ(exp_str[1],return_str[1]);

  CMIString::doubleToString(inp_str[2],return_str[2]);
 EXPECT_EQ(exp_str[2],return_str[2]);

}
```

The code can complie, but when executing, there is no pass or fail status.

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from StringTests
[ RUN      ] StringTests.doubleToString
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `TSTRING` defined? If `TSTRING` is defined as C string you have to use `EXPECT_STREQ()` to compare C strings. If you want to compare string objects you shall use `EXPECT_EQ`.